# Pl/SQL output is not getting aligned properly in OUTLOOK

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

We are using a pl/SQL procedure to print the output of a SQL statement in Microsoft Outlook to all the business users, But the output does not get aligned properly and I have tried all the padding options in the pl/SQL procedure still the output has wavered. Is there a way we can provide fixed with to it?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: PL/SQL is just writing text.  The _rendering_ of that text is up to Outlook, and it is using a proportional-width font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know *how* you're doing this, but

- if it is pure text, use non-proportional font (such as Courier)
- if it is HTML:

  - see whether enclosing text into `<pre>` tags helps. Why? Because sometimes you'd get *many spaces* switched to a *single space* which spoils the output. For example, if you're displaying contents of the `retval` local variable, you'd

    ```
    retval := '<pre style="font-family: monospace">' || retval || '</pre>';
    ```
  - for nicer formatting, consider using unordered list (starts with the `<ul>` tag; each element has the `<li>` tag)